# Can I call apex method before wire method in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I want to perform some check before I get data using wire method. Is there any way to execute apex method and then get data using wire method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifecycle for LWC is available in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks). This doesn't specifically cover when wires are invoked, but if you [read about wires](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about), you will find that these are:

1. Invoked after the constructor.
2. Only invoked when all the reactive parameters they receive have a defined value.

If your wire takes a reactive parameter (one using the '$name' string placeholder) that you default to undefined and only set from your logic at some point in the LWC processing once you've called your imperative apex then, yes, you can have the wire invoked once the imperative call is complete and you set the property behind that reactive parameter's placeholder.

If your wire doesn't take reactive parameters, you'll need to convert this wire into an imperative call instead in order to allow you to choose when to invoke it.